# onItemClicklistener in gridview is not working

Tags: android, onitemclicklistener

I have made a tabs in which I've used gridview to display images , `textviews`...I want to make listener...so that when user click on photo in `gridview` ..it moves to next activity thats is image_description activity.

This is the activity code.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    public HomeFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
       View vew= inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_art_dic,container,false);
        final GridView gridview = (GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        gridview.setDrawSelectorOnTop(true);

        List<ItemObject> allItems = getAllItemObject();
        CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), allItems);
        gridview.setAdapter(customAdapter);


        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    private List<ItemObject> getAllItemObject(){
        List<ItemObject> items = new ArrayList<>();
        items.add(new ItemObject(R.drawable.painting,"Dip It Low", "Christina Milian"));
        items.add(new ItemObject(R.drawable.paintingo,"Someone like you", "Adele Adkins"));
        items.add(new ItemObject(R.drawable.drawing,"Ride", "Ciara"));
        items.add(new ItemObject(R.drawable.sketchbook,"Paparazzi", "Lady Gaga"));
        items.add(new ItemObject(R.drawable.drawing,"Forever", "Chris Brown"));
        items.add(new ItemObject(R.drawable.paintingo,"Stay", "Rihanna"));
        items.add(new ItemObject(R.drawable.sketchbook,"Marry me", "Jason Derulo"));
        items.add(new ItemObject(R.drawable.painting,"Waka Waka", "Shakira"));
        items.add(new ItemObject(R.drawable.drawing,"Dark Horse", "Katy Perry"));
        items.add(new ItemObject(R.drawable.paintingo,"Dip It Low", "Christina Milian"));
        items.add(new ItemObject(R.drawable.painting,"Dip It Low", "Christina Milian"));
        items.add(new ItemObject(R.drawable.sketchbook,"Dip It Low", "Christina Milian"));
        return items;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
     ItemObject image= (ItemObject) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),photo_description.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

Here is how it looks like

[image]

Comment: Post your `Custom Adapter` code.

Comment: you set the on item click twice

Comment: Post your Custom Adapter and item_child of GirdView

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have set multiple itemClickListeners.
Remove below code from onCreateView.

```
 gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
```

Comment: `gridview.setOnItemClickListener(this);` line is already avalaible in code before `gridview.setDrawSelectorOnTop(true);`  line

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK yep.. sorry, i missed it.

Answer (score 0):

> onItemClicklistner is not working

Because setting `onItemClicklistner` two times for same GridView, so last call of `onItemClicklistner` will work and show a Toast message on click of GridView items.

To move to next Activity on click of Item, remove  second call of `setOnItemClickListener` method

Answer (score 0):

**Remove this part From your code.**

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      }
 });
```

> Because this is what you have already defined and made it twice.

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

> Then add `onClickListener` method and do what you want.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
 //do what you want to do when button is clicked
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.gridview:
            // Switch Activity here
            break;
        case default:
            break; 
    }
}
```